# Column values A1, A1, A1, how to convert to A1-1, A1-2, A1-3

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a dataset that has the feature Batch ID, with each batch ID occuring 3 times.

I am looking to create a new feature ProdBatchNo that looks like the following:

```
| Batch ID | ProdBatchNo |
|----------|-------------|
| A1       | A1-1        |
| A1       | A1-2        |
| A1       | A1-3        |
| B1       | B1-1        |
| B1       | B1-2        |
| B1       | B1-3        |
```

My code looks like this

```
E = []
count = 1
for i in df['Batch ID']:    
    if (df['Batch ID'].iloc[i].str[:1] > df['Batch ID'].iloc[i-1].str[:1]):
        count = 1
        E.append(i + str(count))
    else:
        count += 1
        E.append(i + str(count))
```

Error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [A1] of <class 'str'>
```

How can I split this column batch ID to generate the ProdBatchNo column?
Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.